# Unity scrollview inherit scale and keep position relative to parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add some buttons to a gameObject which is a scroll view child. The child is a very wide image, about 4 times as wide as normal screens, which is why I let it control the height, so that it is always from top to bottom, and only exeeds horizontally where scroll is allowed.

[image]
*Here you can see my setting.*

**1.** is the wide image

**2.** is a banner that used to be part of the image, but now I want it to be a individual gameObject.

I don't know how I can make the banner (2) inherit the behavior of the "full map" (1), right now when I choose free aspect and resized the game view, the "full map" scales nicely, so the it always fits from top to bottem. The more narrow the screen is, then more of the map will exceed to the right, and vice versa.

However the problem is that then banner (2) has a rect transform, which is set with x,y coordinates relative to the parent which scales. So as i resize around the view, the banner gets out of it's intended position, and also does not scale with the. I have tried many different components, but without luck. Here among, scale constraint, canvas scaler, position constraint

[image]

As you can see in this gif, the banner does not scale down, as the island gets smaller, also it stays in the same position horizontally.

Any suggestions on how I can make the children os the map behave as they were part of the map?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted previous, misunderstood the question.

Proposed solution:

You remove the map part from UI and create it as an object: You attach the map image as a texture to (ie) a plane (see a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dF15FW3DuN0)). You add the "infinity island" as another texture and have it placed over the island image.
After that, you control the camera to zoom in/out of the island and not struggle with any scaling or moving UI.

Comment: I already tried this. And it help that the banner at least scales, but it doesn't follow its intended position. I think this is due to the key difference that my parent never changes aspect ratio? (also it scales way too much)

Comment: hm, how about not scaling anything but just moving the camera?

Comment: Not sure if that will work. as it is intended to scroll the map horizontally. That is why I placed it inside a scroll view inside a canvas. The reason I have fixed the bottom to top to match canvas height, is due to responsiveness. On very wide screens I still want to show map full height, and then just some more width, than on narrow screens. In this way, the banner (and other clickable objects) will not suddenly be outside the screen on different devices, or yes, outside the screen to the right, but then you just scroll the map to reveal those.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think you need to anchor the images to center of the island mini image, you can drag the anchor gizmo from the scene hierarchy.

If you see it as `free aspect` it gets buggy and difficult to handle, but if you choose a resolution everything is smooth.

Is this what you want?

Change the resolultion

[image]

Comment: Hey! :) can you elaborate a little ? What is "the anchor gizmo" ?

Comment: Also... the island, is just par of a very very large image, that is why the island scales perfectly with the background and all the clouds when i resize the window. The banner however, is its' own object, and does not behave as if it was part of the image, but it should.

Comment: I edited my response, tell me if that is what you want

Comment: Hey, yes this looks like what I want. But the only reason I want this is to support responsiveness. My game is gonna run on all sorts of devices with different screen ratios and sizes. And since my map (parent of the banner) is forced in a fixed aspect ratio due to scroll view settings, I believe it should be possible some how.

Comment: I think now that you need another approach, make it UI-less with multiple images for everything and modify camera only for zoom and stuff.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is not possible this way... But changing approach would mean that I would have to implement a lot of logic to scroll the map horizontally without a scroll view. Also, the camera must never zoom, it will have to be locked bottom to bottom, and top to top with the map. But that would indeed keep the scale and positioning of the child object relative to the parent.

Comment: Unity Canvases can be set to always follow Width or Height, if you match one you only need to bother about horizontal scroll or vertical scroll

Comment: Now I have been trying around with that approach. And it ends up with the exact same result. I set my canavas to screen overlay so it always matches the screen. I then put the map as child, anchor is to point left, stretch height. I then added aspect ratio fitter, with options height controls width, set the ratio as the ratio of the image, this forces it to be correct ratio and bottom to top always match canvas bottom to top. However, no matter what setting is give the banner (the child) it scales wrong and gets out of position. :(

Comment: If i open the map in Photoshop. paste in the banner put it on the desired position and scale. delete the map and keep everything except the banner transparent and save png. Then import the banner on the and choose stretch. It will now be positioned and scaled corretly no matter the screen size and dimension. But why is this behavior so difficult to acheive with standard unity Rect Transform setting.

Comment: The problem is not in the canvas, is in your view of the Game window, change the resolution for fixed resolution examples, the problem is that in free aspect is behaves weird, add if you want 20 different resolutions but in free aspect this wont work properly, screens fix that resolution anyway on the build.

Comment: That is not true ;^) I asked this exact question 3 different dev forums, still no cigar. I then put it up on freelancer and made a pilot project. within 1 hour, and Indian guy had configured my canvases exactly is I need. Unfortunately I am not really qualified to post the answer/solution, because I am not 100% sure exactly what he did to make it work. But it works, and involved zero scripting, only pure unity configuration. (will try to post a solution later today)